# how can show multiple alert together on ios mobile phone

Tags: react-native

```
for(let i=1;i<=4;i++) {
  console.log("hello ", i);
  Alert.alert( "Alert Title", "My Alert Msg", [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }] );
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What do you exactly want to do? What is the current result of your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.